# Use private npm package hosted on GitHub in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify

We built a private NPM package which we're hosting on GitHub for our organization. Our application is deployed in AWS Amplify, so Amplify needs access to this GitHub repository.

I see different feasible solutions, but is there another one?

- add an oauth token from GitHub in the package.json dependencies (we will not do that)
- use the aws-cdk to add the token from AWS secure storage and add it in an npm i command while on preBuild stage -> this makes lokal testing messy and is in my opinion a messy approach anyway
- publish the package on AWS CodeArticfact (possible solution for us)
- use GitHub actions to deploy on AWS (possible solution for us)

Comment: Hey, What did u end up doing? Got the same problem on my end. Want to use some private packages but not sure how to ship them over.

Comment: We ended up with moving our build process to GitHub Actions and pushing the artifacts to a S3 bucket. IMO generally a cleaner solution, but it takes some time to setup. Be aware that GitHub documentation is really poor about integrating private GitHub Packages into Actions, but this comment did the trick: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/49#issuecomment-1293249466